# MVC3 Custom Validation error message doesn't display when using ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

**SUMMARY**

`Question:` Why doesn't the custom validation error message show when using a ViewModel.

`Answer:` The custom validation should be applied to the ViewModel not the Class.  See the end of @JaySilk84's answer for example code.

MVC3, project using

- jquery-1.7.2.min.js
- modernizr-2.5.3.js
- jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js (generated by jQuery.com for the Accordion plugin)
- jquery.validate.min.js and
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

I have validation working in my project for both dataannotations in the View and for ModelState.AddModelError in the Controller so I know I have all the validation code configured properly.

But with custom validation an error is generated in the code but the error message doesn't display.

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{ if (DOB > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18))
  { yield return new ValidationResult("Must be 18 or over."); }      }
```

Drilling down in debug in the POST action the custom validation causes Model state to fail and the error message is placed in the proper value field but when the model is sent back to the view the error message doesn't display.  In the controller I also have ModelState.AddModelError code and its message does display.  How is that handled differently as to one would work and not the other?  If not that what else would prevent the error message from displaying?

**Update 1 :**

I'm using a ViewModel to create the model in the view.  I stripped out the ViewModel and the error message started displaying, as soon I added the ViewModel back in the message again stopped displaying.  Has anyone successfully used a custom validation with a ViewModel?  Was there anything you had to do extra to get it to work?

**Update 2 :**

I created a new MVC3 project with these two simple classes (Agency and Person).

```
  public class Agency : IValidatableObject
  {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
      if (DOB > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18)) { yield return new ValidationResult("Must be over 18."); }
    }
  }

  public class Person
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

Here's the Controller Code

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Agency/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Agency agency)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {

        db.Agencies.Add(agency);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }

      return View(agency);
    }
    
    //[HttpPost]
    //public ActionResult Create(AgencyVM agencyVM)
    //{
    //  if (ModelState.IsValid)
    //  {
    //    var agency = agencyVM.Agency;
    //    db.Agencies.Add(agency);
    //    db.SaveChanges();
    //    return RedirectToAction("Index");
    //  }

    //  return View(agencyVM);
    //}
```

The View

```
@model CustValTest.Models.Agency
@*@model CustValTest.Models.AgencyVM*@
@* When using VM (model => model.Name)  becomes (model => model.Agency.Name) etc. *@

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Agency</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

The ViewModel

```
  public class AgencyVM
  {
    public Agency Agency { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }

  }
```

When just Agency is presented in the View the validation error displays (DOB under 18).  When the ViewModel is presented the error doesn't display.  The custom validation always catches the error though and causes ModelState.IsValid to fail and the view to be re-presented.   Can anyone replicate this?  Any ideas on why and how to fix?

**Update 3 :**

As a temporary work around I have changed the Validation into a field level one (vs. a model level one) by adding a parameter to the ValidationResult:

```
if (DOB > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18)) { yield return new ValidationResult("Must be over 18.", new [] { "DOB" }); }
```

The problem with this is now the error message is showing up next to the field rather than at the top of the form (which is not good in say an accordion view since the user will be returned to the form with no visible error message).  To fix this secondary problem I added this code to the Controller POST action.

```
      ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, errMsgInvld);
      return View(agencyVM);
    }
    string errMsgInvld = "There was an entry error, please review the entire form. Invalid entries will be noted in red.";
```

The question is still unanswered, why doesn't the model level error message show with a ViewModel (see my response to JaySilk84 for more on this)?

Comment: Can you show us your view (e.g. Razor's *.cshtml) file which the error message is supposed to display on. Are you using the `@Html.Validation*` built-in methods or something else to display the errors?

Comment: No problem with the display code, see my updated question.  I'm using a viewmodel, as soon as I stripped the viewmodel out of the view the error message started showing up.

Comment: I built a simplified model that fails and posted the code.  See update 2 in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is now that your models are nested, the error message is being placed into ModelState under `Agency` without the .DOB because you didn't specify it in the `ValidationResult`. The `ValidationMessageFor()` helper is looking for a key named *Agency.DOB* (see relevant code below from ValidationMessageFor() helper):

```
string fullHtmlFieldName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(expression);
FormContext clientValidation = htmlHelper.ViewContext.GetFormContextForClientValidation();
if (!htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(fullHtmlFieldName) && clientValidation == null)
    return (MvcHtmlString) null;
```

`GetFullHtmlFieldName()` is returning *Agency.DOB*, not *Agency*

I think if you add the DOB to the `ValidationResult` it will work:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (DOB > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18)) { yield return new ValidationResult("Must be over 18.", new List<string>() { "DOB" }); }
}
```

That second parameter to `ValidationResult` will tell it what key to use in ModelState (By default it will append the parent object which is `Agency`) so the ModelState will have a key named *Agency.DOB* which is what your `ValidationMessageFor()` is looking for.

**Edit:**

<strike>If you don't want field level validation then you don't need the `Html.ValidationMessageFor()`. You just need the `ValidationSummary()`.</strike>

The view is treating `AgencyVM` as the model. If you want it to validate properly then put the validation at the `AgencyVM` level and have it validate the child objects. Alternatively you could put validation on the child objects but the parent object (AgencyVM) has to aggregate it to the view. Another thing you can do is keep it as it is and change `ValidationSummary(true)` to `ValidationSummary(false)`. This will print everything in ModelState to the summary. I think removing the validation from `Agency` and putting it on `AgencyVM` might be the best approach:

```
 public class AgencyVM : IValidatableObject

    {
        public Agency Agency { get; set; }

        public Person Person { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (Agency.DOB > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18)) { yield return new ValidationResult("Must be over 18."); }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Agency.Name)) { yield return new ValidationResult("Need a name"); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whether you have ViewModel or not the ModelState has three keys. "Name", "DOB" and "" or with ModelState "Agency.Name", "Agency.DOB" and "Agency".  The custom Validation will display the model level "" error meesage but not the "Agency" one. Adding a parameter to the ValidationResult turns into a field level validation, not a  model level, so the error message is placed next to the field not at the top of the form (where I want it).  I have already used the field level validation in a temporary work around which I will post momentarily as update 3.

Comment: The question is still unanswered.  To refine it further why doesn't the model level error message show?

Comment: @Joe The model is AgencyVM and it has two properties, not models.

Comment: JaySilk84 The first sentence should read "... or with the ViewModel "Agency.Name", ... I didn't say properties or models, I said keys and there are three of them.

Comment: JaySilk84 The answer to my question is that the custom validation has to be on the ViewModel, as in your revised answer, not the class.  I checked your code and it works.  You should keep the Html.ValidationMessageFor() to catch any client side validation  off of the class properties attributes.  Along that line I would use the [Required] attribute on the Name property in the Agency class to get client side validation for the Name property rather than having to POST back for validation. Thank you

Comment: @Joe Totally agree about the ValidationMessageFor(), I actually don't know what I was thinking this morning. The validation for the name in my edit was just an example. Glad you got it working though :)